# Semantic markup for image caption rollovers?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I'm working on an image caption rollover effect for my site and it's pretty much done.  I'm using a combination of CSS and jQuery.

It looks something like this...

[image]

It works well.  The caption appears to the left of the image whenever you mouseover the image.

However, I'm getting a warning in Visual Studio that an `h2` tag cannot be placed inside of a label according to XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Here's the markup I'm working with...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/controls/27/saturation-rollover-effect">
            <label class="info">
                <h2>Saturation Rollover Effect</h2>
                <p>Product description here...</p>
            </label>
            <img src="/thumbnail/small/27-saturation-rollover-effect.jpg" alt="Saturation Rollover Effect" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've also tried a `span` in place of the `label`, and I get the same message.  I've also tried a `div`, but div's are not supposed to be inside of the `a` tag.

I'd prefer to keep all of this inside of the link like I have it to get the SEO benefit from the text.  But I'd also like to be XHTML Transitional compliant, and semantic/meaningful at the same time.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think a `label` is the element you're thinking of, they're `form` elements, to associate the [label being defined with another control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1): [XHTML Transitional DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html). Also, it's an in-line element, and shouldn't contain (so far as I can tell, though that's without external reference) block-level elements.

Comment: @David - I had actually tried a `span` first.  The `label` was just me grasping at straws, but I probably shouldn't use it anyway.

Comment: You can't place an `h2` or a `p` anywhere in an `a` tag either for that matter, not just `div`

Comment: As far as I can recall *no* block-level element should be within an `a` element ([prior to HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/), and even then it's only within an `a` element); so your mark-up would *seem* invalid from the get-go. Incidentally, have you considered using a [`dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `label` is for form elements--not images.

An `h2` is acceptable, though you'd typically want to use that for larger blocks of content usually.

HTML5 has introduced `figure` and `figcaption` which might be appropriate in this situation:

http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

As for wrapping it in an `a` tag, that probably doesn't make sense unless the href resolves to a valid URI sans JavaScript. Since it's a roll-over effect, clicking a link woudldn't be applicable.

Answer (score 2):

After a little rethink I came up with something that works and makes sense, I think...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="info">
            <h2><a href="/controls/27/saturation-rollover-effect">Saturation Rollover Effect</a></h2>
            <p>Product description here...</p>
        </div>
        <a href="/controls/27/saturation-rollover-effect"><img src="/thumbnail/small/27-saturation-rollover-effect.jpg" alt="Saturation Rollover Effect" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I had to break the caption away from the link around the image.  Then I added a link around the title of the product (which is probably more useful for SEO anyway).  And this is valid XHTML.  Thanks to David Thomas and BoltClock for the comments.

UPDATE:

This is live on my site now.  It's functional in IE8, but not quite as pretty as it is in IE9, Chrome, or Firefox.  And then I might make the thumbnails grayscale for a cleaner look.  Overall it seems to work pretty well though... http://www.silverlightxap.com/